# How to keep Flask use_reloader working while Debug is False?

Tags: ajax, flask

my Flask app was launching twice , so I have tried "debug=False" , but this is preventing auto reload while i am changing ajax code . 
so i am starting my app like this 
if **name** == '**main**':
    app.run(debug=False, use_reloader=True ,host='0.0.0.0', port=4002)

but auto_reload is not working

Answer (score 4):

Official `Flask Documentation` says:

> `debug` must be True (i.e., exceptions must be caught) in order for the other two options (i.e `use_reloader` and `use_debugger`) to have any value.

So that means, with `debug=False`, `use_reloader` ain't gonna have any value to work with and as a result, you won't get what you want.